# How to generate H323 (Including H225 & H245) protocol packets?

Tags: network-programming, asterisk, voip, wireshark-dissector, h.323

I'm trying to write a simple DPI (Deep Packet Inspection) tool. In my current phase, I need to develop a H.323 protocol detector. To aim this goal I need a H.225 / H.245 packet generator. I seems that almost all tool use SIP and RTP & RTCP protocol. Does anybody have any idea which tool use H323 protocols in VOIP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is number of h323 libraries, some of them are openh323 and openoh323/openooh323.

But ALL libraries have issues and alot of bugs. Main issue - protocol is VERY complex if compare with sip or other modern protocols and ALL vendors do "vendor-specific" addons/changes in protocol way they think "better for client".

As result it is hard to work with any tools. Easy way detect is just get signatures like 'h323', 'rtp' etc.

Comment: _Easy way detect is just get signatures like 'h323', 'rtp' etc._ Well, the problem is that I can't find any signature for H323 packet! Is there any specific header or signature for H225, H245, H323 packets?

Comment: You can also check iptables filters, i am pretty sure there are some connection tracking filters in iptables exists. THAT for sure have signatures.